# platformexception in firebase auth

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, dart-null-safety

Error: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PlatformException'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'PlatformException' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/message_codec.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codec.dart').
  platformExceptionToFirebaseAuthException(exception),
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/e-tech/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/home/e-tech/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

take a look if you that Object that you want to use is from Firebase package or from Dart, in this case you are using dart:core but there's also firebase_core.

I assume you are using a class upon which it takes an Object as an argument, would be good if i see the code, but if is not working put dynamic instead and then along the way you'll figure out what's the issue.